# Regular expression for length limit 10 digit before decimal till 2 decimal place with Number only?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want a regular expression for length limit 10 digit with 2 decimal place  numbers with only numbers allowed.10 digit before decimal 
**allowed** 
1 
1111111111 
111 
1111111111.22 
.2 
1.2 
1.22 
 
**Not allowed** 
 4.
 . 
-1 
abc 
Null 
Emptystring 
"" 
1.222 
-1.22 
111111111111 
tried but not working

```
^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Comment: How did you devise this regex? Your regex doesn't match the `-` character for sign.

Comment: @CertainPerformance fixed

Comment: Do you want to match `1.2`? or `1.22`

Comment: @vks both needed

Comment: @DeepakJain .2 ?

Comment: yes man .2 also

Comment: @DeepakJain the answer u accepted accepts `.` as well.`1.` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there - all you have to do is include a check that the string is not empty (which can be accomplished with a positive lookahead for `.{1,10}` right after the `^`), and check that its first digit string has at most 10 characters (just use a `{0,10}` quantifier for the digits). Also note that `[0-9]` simplifies to `\d`.

In order to also exclude trailing dots, repeat the digit after the dot with `{1,2}` instead of `{0,2}`:

```
^(?!$)\d{0,10}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ah8dNu/5

Comment: 11111111111 (11 digit are invalid) not working (only 10 digit allowed)

Comment: 10 digit before Decimal

Comment: @vks I did notice that, OP had `{0,2}` in his original code rather than `{1, 2}`, seemed strange but I *thought* it was intentional

Comment: @DeepakJain use `^(?!$)\d{0,10}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` . See demo. https://regex101.com/r/Ah8dNu/4

Comment: @DeepakJain Can you clarify whether you want to accept a single `.`? Your original regex had `(?:\.\d{0,2})`, which seemed odd, but I copied it because it seemed intentional, but if not, it's a simple tweak

Comment: @DeepakJain See edit, just change the `{0` to `{1` to require at least one digit

Answer (score 0):

I have also prepared below RegEx.

Seems this will also work.

[^[0-9]{1,10}((\.)[0-9]{0,2}){0,1}$](https://regexr.com/4302a)